# How to move Layout when scrollView scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-animation

[image]

Hello everyone, i want to hide linearLayout when scrolllView scrolling up. 
I try to make next:
 When I move my finger up on 1 px- move linearLayout up on 1 px, when LinearLayout become invisible, after that - move scrollview to top.

```
 scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {                 
                    downXValue = event.getX();
                    downYValue = event.getY();
                    previousYvalue = downYValue;
                    break;
                }


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    float currentY = event.getY();
                    if (downYValue < currentY) {
                        previousYvalue = 0;                   
                        ((CompanyInfoActivityNew) getActivity()).setPanelMargin(0);
                        margin=0;
                        Log.v("", "down");

                    }
                    if (downYValue > currentY) {
                        previousYvalue = 0;
                        ((CompanyInfoActivityNew) getActivity()).setPanelMargin(-230);
                        margin=-230;
                        Log.v("", "up");

                    }
                    //  }
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    if (Math.abs(previousYvalue - event.getY()) >2) {
                        previousYvalue = event.getY();
                        switch ((int) margin) {
                            case 0://LinearLayout is visible
                                if ((event.getY() - downYValue) < 0) {
                                    margin = ((event.getY() - downYValue)) / 2;
                                    ((CompanyInfoActivityNew) getActivity()).movePanel(margin);
                                } else {
                                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                                }
                                break;

                            case -230://linearLayout is invisible
                                if ((event.getY() - downYValue) > 0) {
                                    margin = ((event.getY() - downYValue)) / 2;
                                    ((CompanyInfoActivityNew) getActivity()).movePanel(margin);
                                } else {
                                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                                }
                                break;

                            default:
                                if ((event.getY() - downYValue)>=-230 &&(event.getY() - downYValue)<=230  ) {
                                    margin = ((event.getY() - downYValue)) / 2;
                                    ((CompanyInfoActivityNew) getActivity()).movePanel(margin);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


public void movePanel(double margin) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout1.getLayoutParams();
    int tempMargin = params.topMargin + (int) margin;
    if (tempMargin <= 0 && tempMargin >= -210) {
        params.setMargins(0, tempMargin, 0, 0);
        linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Android-ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView), it has many examples of this type of animation and it's a lot more simple than what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you, it is usefull link, but it applies only actionBars?

Comment: It applies to any view, not only with actionbars. Some examples show the use of a `Toolbar` but it could be any other view you like. See https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/observablescrollview-samples/src/main/res/layout/activity_toolbarcontrollistview.xml, where you have two views, one is the `ObservableListView` and the other one is just a `LinearLayour` but it could be anything.

Comment: Thank you, o Woill try it, if it helps me - i check your answer.

Comment: this solution works. i have implemented. it should be marked as the answer